# Django search filter vs Javascript query search filter?

Tags: javascript, search, filter, django-rest-framework

I want to know which searching will be more efficient and faster in comparison between a django search and js query search. I'm trying to implement search for my project and want to decide which one will the best.

Currently i'm using js search query, as i have large number of data i wanted to know which search will be the most reliable, best and efficient.

For more clarification in my Django-project i'm using this currently

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    type          : 'category',
    minCharacters : 3,
    apiSettings   : {
      onResponse: function(githubResponse) {
        var
          response = {
            results : {}
          }
        ;

        $.each(githubResponse.items, function(index, item) {
          var
            language   = item.language || 'Unknown',
            maxResults = 8
          ;
          if(index >= maxResults) {
            return false;
          }
          // create new language category
          if(response.results[language] === undefined) {
            response.results[language] = {
              name    : language,
              results : []
            };
          }

          response.results[language].results.push({
            title       : item.name,
            description : item.description,
            url         : item.html_url
          });
        });
        return response;
       },
      url: 'https://myurl?q={query}'
    }
  })
```

So, my question is what happens when a large number of data are present, in that case is this will be the best approach or django-search filter will be the best approach.

Comment: There is no code provided in this question, so I gave a downvote and my answer is my opinion based on what teams I have worked in use. Do the filter with Django.

Comment: Any particular reason why django search not js query search, i just wanted to know which one will be more efficient and reliable with reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Djiago is a framework,Js is a program language.But ,Djiago's language is python,If it's Python and JS, I feel they are not comparable.

Comment: The application environment for both is completely different

Comment: I have provided more info for the question if u can help please i want to know which search is more efficient and why.